# Android: Getting a friend and chat history with him from Facebook messenger

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

Is it possible to start an intent from my android app to select a friend from Facebook messenger and get the conversation history with him? If yes how such intent should look like? Or do I have to use Facebook SDK for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for several reasons:

- First of all, you would need to select friends by using `/me/friends`, but you don´t get a list of ALL friends. Since v2.0 of the Graph API, you only get friends who authorized your App too.
- You would need to get the `read_mailbox` permission approved by Facebook. But that permission [will not get approved](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_mailbox) for Android Apps.

If that would be possible, an App would be able to get access to the messages of the friends of the authorized user. Which would obviously be a pretty heavy privacy issue. Just so you understand what this is not possible at all.

Comment: Friends could be retrieved using this method: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends but it looks like reading messages is a real problem. But I don't really get the reason for that restriction. I would like to read the messages only of the person who has authenticated with my app, not his friends. That should be allowed IMO.

Comment: I have just found an Android app that requires access to "messages": https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mwasiluk.facebookreader&hl=en and then is successfully reading them...

Comment: Or here is another example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.squanda.swoop.app it gets the messages from Facebook messager, any ideas how this was done?

Comment: those are old v1.0 apps, they will stop working after april 2015, when v1.0 apps will get upgraded to v2.0 and have to go through the review process too

Comment: read the last paragraph of my answer again. you can´t just get access to the user messages and NOT get access to what his friends wrote. it´s very important to protect the privacy of those who do not use an app, that´s why the restriction is there for a very good reason.

Comment: Thanks. The current applications that are accessing messages were misleading for me. Didn't know they will cease to work after April 2015.